# conditonal expectation second moment of a symmetric random variable

Tags: conditional-expectation

Given a random variable say $X$ which is symmetric about some point $a$.
If I define another random variable Y whose expectation $E[Y|X=x] = f(x)$.

Is there a mechanism to say something about the second moment $E[Y^2|X]$ in terms of X?